# Array to string conversion insert to database

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have a problem with array to string again. But this time I need insert to database.

```
Checks::find($id)->update($request->all());
$issue[] = $request->issue;

foreach ($issue as $item) {
    dd($item);
    addIssues::create([
        'check_id' => $id,
        'issue_id' => $item
    ]);
}
```

Migration:

```
Schema::create('checks_issues', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('check_id');
    $table->string('issue_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->primary(['check_id','issue_id']);
});
```

Comment: Please show the results of `dd($request->issue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($issue as $item){
        foreach ($item as $item1){
            addIssues::create([
                'check_id' => $id,
                'issue_id' => $item1
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Checks::find($id)->update($request->all());
    if(!empty($request->issue)){
       $issue = explode(',',$request->issue);

     foreach ($issue as $item){

        addIssues::create([
            'check_id' => $id,
            'issue_id' => $item
        ]);
     }
    }
```

Comment: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given